# вставить одномерный массив в двумерный

Tags: c#, массивы, строки, файлы, преобразование

у меня есть небольшая проблема есть файл который записан в опредленном порядке но существует проблема мне необходимо извлечь данные и переписать этот фаил в другом порядке а именно оригинал записан так что немного напоминает csv фаил но не распознается таковым по этому прибегают к написанию данного кода необходимо все слова записать в массив затем данный массив преобразовать в двумерный массив при условии что каждые каждые 49 элементов массива ( одномерного ) записать на новою строку я аписал короткий кусочек кода но он роботает чястично

```
class Program
{
public static bool ender = true;
public static int I, P;
public static string co = ",";
public  const int ele = 49;
static void Main(string[] args)
{        
    string lin = @"C:\Users\SomeUser\Desktop\New folder (7)\flltest.txt";
    using (StreamReader fs = new StreamReader(lin, 
     Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1255")))

        while (true)
        {

            string temp = fs.ReadLine();
            Char delimiter = ',';
            String[] substrings = temp.Split(delimiter);
            string[,] Hum = new string[P,I];
            while (ender == true)
            {
                for (int P = 1; P < substrings.Length/49 ; P++)
                {
                    for (int I = 1; I < 49 ; I++)
                    {
                        Hum[P,I] = substrings[I];
                    }
                }
              ender = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

я провел тщательный дебаг кода но увы по отсутствию знаний двумерный массив не получить значение от одномерного массива
была еще одна идея присвоить значения определенного индекса одномерного массива к локальной переменной но там тоже не получилось 
 **зарание благодарю за помощь**

Comment: Почему не записать в List<string[ ]> ?

Comment: Даже лучше наверное List<List<string>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вы объявили статические поля `I` и `P`. И создали массив с размерами `I` на `P`. Но нигде эти поля не инициализировали. Они у Вас равны нулю. Соответственно, `string[,] Hum = new string[P,I];` - эквивалентно `string[,] Hum = new string[0,0];`. Возможно, это нужно записать как `new string[substrings.Length/ele, ele];`. Но Вы объявляете этот массив для каждой считанной строки. Возможно, это правильно. Но я не уверен.
2. Индексы в C# начинаются  с нуля. Т.е. циклы тоже должны идти с нуля, а не с единицы.
3. Проверки на то, что Вы считали хотя бы что-то из файла нет. Соответственно, когда дойдём до конца - Вы об этом никак не узнаете и получите исключение.
4. Очень, очень, ОЧЕНЬ плохая идея сначала объявить поле/свойство класса, а потом использовать такие же обозначения для объявления переменной цикла. Да, это объявление "спрячет" поле. И это отличный способ запутать вероятного противника. Но в данном случае противник - это Вы сами.

Comment: 1.количество строк мне не известно но количество ячеек в строке 48 я планирую рассчитывать количество строк взяв длину substrings и разделив на 49

Comment: 2.я знаю об этом причина почему я начал с 1 а не с 0 втом что первое слово файл не является значимым

Comment: 3. проверка была совершена переменная завершающая это ender просто немного ошибся с кодом это должно быть не  while (true)
а  while (ender)

Comment: на счет 4 не спорю  пожалуйста дайте совет как это правельно написать зарание  благодарю за уделенное внимание внимани

Comment: еще один важный момент эта программа является скелетом для не большого преобразователя таких файлов в конце концов программа должна записать все данные в таблицы при использовании WPF

Comment: 1. Если количество строк совсем не известно (т.е. Вы не знаете сколько строк в файле и сколько будет строк в итоговом массиве) - возможно, стоит действительно использовать `List<string[]>`, как предлагал @Digital-Core, формировать для каждой строки отдельный одномерный массив размером 48 и после заполнения добавлять его в список.

Comment: 4. Уберите поля P и I. Они не используются в Вашем алгоритме. Их объявление похоже на объявление переменных в Pascal, но в C# этого не нужно.

Comment: благодарю за помощь